# PHPUnit simple method to compare two dates

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I'm not familiar with PHPUnit and just want to execute a simple method that return a DateTimeImmutable and compare it with another DateTimeImmutable.

```
    public function testGetLunchTimesBeginHour()
{
    $minLunchTime = \DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat('H:i', self::MIN_BEGIN_LUNCH);
    $maxLunchTime = \DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat('H:i', self::MAX_END_LUNCH);

    foreach($this->daysOfAppointments as $dayOfAppointments){
        $appointments = $this->makeAppointmentsDatetime($dayOfAppointments);
        $mock = $this->getMockBuilder(GetLunchTimesBeginHour::class)->getMock();
        $expected = \DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat('H:i', $dayOfAppointments['expected']);
        $actualResult = $mock->expects($this->once())->method('getLunch')->with($appointments, $minLunchTime, $maxLunchTime, self::DURATION_LUNCH);


        $this->assertEquals(
            $expected,
            $actualResult,
            "unexpected result");
    }
}
```

I understand the problem is that $actualResult is a PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\Builder\InvocationMocker instead of a DateTimeImmutable.

How to just execute the method and get the result ? Must I call the real class instead of a mock ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure what you want to test here, but here an example:

```
    $expectedDate = new \DateTimeImmutable('2022-11-01');
    $now = new \DateTimeImmutable('2022-10-01');

    $myClass = new MyClass();
    $newDate = $myClass->calcul($now);

    // ± 5 seconds are equals
    self::assertEqualsWithDelta($expectedDate->getTimestamp(), $newDate->getTimestamp(), 5);
```

And use a foreach in a unit-test is not a good practice, it's better to use a dataProvider

https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit-data-providers

Comment: Finally I didn't need to mock but to use the real method.

Answer (score 0):

I would not mock what you are trying to test. Try something like this, you will need to fill in the gaps and mock any dependancies though. This is assuming that the method `getLunch` returns a dateTime object.

```
public function testGetLunchTimesBeginHour()
{
    $minLunchTime = \DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat('H:i', self::MIN_BEGIN_LUNCH);
    $maxLunchTime = \DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat('H:i', self::MAX_END_LUNCH);


    //Class you are testing, you will need to mock the class dependancies and pass them in.
    $testObject = new GetLunchTimesBeginHour();

    foreach($this->daysOfAppointments as $dayOfAppointments){
        $appointments = $this->makeAppointmentsDatetime($dayOfAppointments);
        $mock = $this->getMockBuilder(GetLunchTimesBeginHour::class)->getMock();
        $expected = \DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat('H:i', $dayOfAppointments['expected']);
     
        //get real response from created object you are testing.
        $actualResult = $testObject->getLunch($appointments, $minLunchTime, $maxLunchTime, self::DURATION_LUNCH);

        $this->assertEquals(
            $expected,
            $actualResult,
            "unexpected result"
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't view your response. I finally just used the object directly without mocking yes. Thanks.